# JPEG XR Plugin for Photoshop Elements 10?

Tags: jpeg, copyright, photoshop-elements

I *think* I took a neat picture of a butterfly that I just used PSE10 to cut out of its background.  Now, I want to package the butterfly as "free" clipart using appropriate tags to preserve my intellectual property.

Is there a decent JPEG XR plugin for PSE10 that supports transparency?  If there is such a plugin, would using the plugin or JPEG XR force me to pay a royalty fee to a company every time I give someone a copy of my butterfly?

I've seen several posts on Bing that there used to be a JPEG XR plugin for older versions of Abobe Photoshop CSX, but all links I find to that plugin *seem* to be broke.  Also, I am a very crude ameture so I don't want to shell out the money for CS6.

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about a JPEG XR Plugin for PSE, however, I would use PNG for my file.

You could download [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and then use the [GIMP JPEG XR Plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25508) to do what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Lynda, I think you are right in implying that PNG is good for clipart, but do most operating systems properly handle PNG tEXt chunks?  I'm thinking that if JPEG XR won't work for me that I might want to consider TIFF.  What do you think about TIFF?  Also, I found a JPEG XR Plugin for Paint.NET that may help until I can find one for PSE10.

Comment: @ShawnEary - When you say tEXt chunks I assume you are referring to metadata? I am not sure how different operating systems will handle it. I know programs like Bridge can read that data easily but a simple program that views photos may not. TIFF is a good format from my expierence. The only drawback I see with TIFF is large file sizes but that is okay in some instances (TIFF is lossless) For myself I would stick with a well used format that would work for my situation be that PNG or TIFF.

Comment: Yes.  The tEXt chunks I was referring to was the metadata.  If I remember correctly, some versions of MS Windows File Manager (formerly known as explorer) have trouble reading PNG metadata.  That's kind of why I was leaning toward TIFF or JPEG XR.  BTW: I think JPEG XR does indeed support lossless encoding with transparency so it *probably* would be good for clipart if it were better supported.

Comment: @ShawnEary - Support for JPEG XR is what would concern me. I had heard of JPEG XR but had to look it up to understand what it was. I am not versed enough about what versions of windows would or would not support PNG metadata. That might be a quesion better asked over on the SuperUser Site: http://superuser.com - I will add that I see a lot of clip art that is in the PNG format.